# Multi module maven project not deploying executable Jar for dependent module

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a multi module maven project. It is set up correctly because when I run maven clean install, it successfully builds all of the modules. Webapp contains common functionality that I need to have in the web service so I have included this as maven dependency within the web service.

Maven reactor summary:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Parent .................................. SUCCESS [  0.420 s]
[INFO] Webapp .................................. SUCCESS [  6.221 s]
[INFO] Webservice .............................. SUCCESS [  5.954 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.763 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-20T16:27:50-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/238M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Eclipse will even the webapp project to the deployment assembly for the web serivce.

[image: Deployment Assembly Configuration]

Here is my maven dependency within my webservice for the webapp module:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.company</groupId>
     <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
     <version>16.3</version>
     <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

However, when I try to run this, I receive the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.model.User
```

To remedy this i have to remove the module from the deployment assembly and actually add the jar that was created in the /target folder. It looks like if I don't do this it will not create the executable jar file in the lib folder on the server but just a folder structure of the webapp project.  Is there a setting I can use to fix this, so it deploys correctly on the server? Any advice is much appreciated because this is my first multi-module maven project and I have been struggling with this for sometime and it is becoming a nuisance. Thanks!

Comment: Are you running the web service with a plugin within eclipse? have you tried to run the web service war built  with maven in a standalone application server? I suspect the problem is with eclipse project metadata.

Comment: I am using the m2e plugin for eclipse. And yes, when I deploy the war generated from the target folder it works correctly, so I also figured it was something with how eclipse is deploying to the server. Just can't figure it out. Note that when I look at the jar inside the deployed war from eclipse, it is a directory.

Comment: I'm afraid I had the same bug several times and never found a solution. Try to remove manually the eclipse support files and re-import the project.

Comment: I found a similar problem with an old version of the eclipse maven plugin: try upgrading m2e to  latest version http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/

Comment: i had tried both solutions, but unfortunately neither of them had worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like eclipse will just look for projects within the workspace to include as a maven dependency, but it adds the project to the dependent project which causes issues when you want to use classes from the other module. I found this is a setting that was checked. Once I unchecked it, it added the jar correctly to the server and I am able to access classes without getting ClassNotFound Exceptions

*Right click on the web project -> Properties -> Maven*

[image]